# Clone sheet, name it, clear cells - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not very good with VBA, but I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- I have a sheet (Week 50) with a table with certain info.
- I want a button (macro) that creates a new sheet (Week 51) that has
  the same table, only the content should be cleared (a certain
  cell-range).
- The first column in the table should be based on a formula of the previous week. How can this be made adaptive to work on every new week?

How can I copy the sheet and determine the name, based on the previous week? And how can I clear certain cells of this new sheet in the same macro?

So far I just have:

```
Sub New_Week()
    Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Copy After:=Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the range of contents you want to clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code doesn't take into account changing years, so if you run it with 52 weeks already in the workbook it will happily create week 53, 54 and so on.

You don't need the current week selected, the code searches for the highest week number based on the sheets being named `Week xx`.
It clears the ranges D2:G2 and H5:K8.
Any reference on the sheet to `'Week xx'!` is updated to the previous week in the same way you would by pressing `Ctrl+H` on the keyboard.

```
Sub CreateNewSheet()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim lWkNum As Long
    Dim lCurNum As Long
    Dim sht_LastWeek As Worksheet
    Dim sht_NewWeek As Worksheet

    'Find previous week and set reference to it.
    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If IsNumeric(Replace(wrkSht.Name, "Week ", "")) Then
            lCurNum = CLng(Replace(wrkSht.Name, "Week ", ""))
            If lCurNum > lWkNum Then lWkNum = lCurNum
        End If
    Next wrkSht
    Set sht_LastWeek = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Week " & lWkNum)

    'Create new sheet, set reference to it and rename.
    sht_LastWeek.Copy After:=Sheets(sht_LastWeek.Index)
    Set sht_NewWeek = Sheets(sht_LastWeek.Index + 1)
    sht_NewWeek.Name = "Week " & lCurNum + 1

    'Clear the cells and relink formula to previous sheet.
    With sht_NewWeek
        .Range("D2:G2,H5:K8").ClearContents
        .Cells.Replace What:="'Week " & lCurNum - 1 & "'!", _
                       Replacement:="'Week " & lCurNum & "'!", _
                       LookAt:=xlPart
    End With

End Sub
```